# Android build failed with 'parser.name must not be null'

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-navigation

In an Android project, build failed with this error:

```
> Task :app:generateSafeArgsDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateSafeArgsDebug'.
> parser.name must not be null
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It may be caused by unhandled files in `res/navigation`.
For instance macOS may add `.DS_Store` files that  may be deleted with:

```
$ rm app/src/main/res/navigation/.DS_Store
```

Comment: oh my god, this saved my day

Comment: great, it worked!!